# A 1/x function that intesects both the x and y axes at specific points, and whose shape can be changed.

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I'm having trouble even naming the function I'm looking for. Here's a [desmos screencap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76b7x.png)
Basically, I want a combination of function f(x) and h(x). Where I can control three things simultaneously: the x-intercept, the y-intercept, and the curve's shape *r*.

Comment: Hi and welcome, please consider reformatting your question with Mathjax, see this tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Another point: it's annoying having to lookup the functions from an image, so please put them in your question. Also, you can have images displayed directly in the question.

Finally, from your question it is still unclear what exactly you want. The equation of the function? The name of the function? The parameters of the function? It would be nice to put some trivial examples and attempts at solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the function doesn’t need to be a hyperbola, you could use $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{a}$, where $a$ is a positive constant.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be

$$ f(x)=\frac{bd(x-a)}{a(x-d)} $$

This gives $y$ intercept $f(0)=b$ and $x$ intercept $f(a)=0$.

Then choosing $d<0$ controls the curvature.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank you!